# How is it possible to model Urelements in ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is it possible for any cardinal number k, to construct in ZFC a set K with cardinality k such that for every element x of K and every element y of K, x is not an element of y and also such that for any set x, if x is a K-set if and only if x is equal to the powerset of a for some a in K, or to the set {a, b} for some a and b in K, or to the powerset of A for some K-set a, or to the set {a, b}, for sone K-sets a and b; then, if x is a K-set then for every element a of K, a is not an element of x?

If it is possible to construct such a set K in ZFC then it is possible to model urelements in ZFC, which is what I’m trying to do.

Comment: Would you please rephrase your question to avoid an extremely dense run-on sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't have the patience to decipher the first paragraph of the question, but it is certainly possible to interpret set theory with urelements in ZFC. One way to do it is as follows.

Let $\kappa$ be the cardinal number that you want to be the number of urelements. Define a version of the cumulative hierarchy as follows. Let $V_0=\{0\}\times\kappa$. For every ordinal $\alpha>0$, let $V_\alpha$ be the set of ordered pairs $(1,x)$ where $x$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta$. The universe of the interpretation is $\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha$, and the membership relation $E$ is defined by $(i,x)E(j,y)\iff j=1$ and $(i,x)\in y$.

The idea behind this definition is that you use ordered pairs $(0,x)$ to represent urelements and use ordered pairs $(1,x)$ to represent sets. You start with the desired number of urelements (in $V_0$), and then you build the usual cumulative hierarchy of sets over this base, using the tag 1 to keep the sets different from the urelements.

Comment: I'd suggest maybe using a different letter than $V_\alpha$ for the cumulative hierarchy here. Maybe $U_\alpha$?